# RecyclerView not clearing (notifyDataSetChanged not working)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I've had a look everywhere on here and nothing is related to my problem. Basically I've implemented a feature which changes the reading direction of my app (1 or -1) now I can get it to initially change direction and it works really well but when I get it to change back (using the same code but changing the direction) it just doesn't update. Just seems like **notifyDataSetChanged();** doesn't want to work the second time...?

My code is as as follows:

```
private void flip() {

    if (!isFlipped) {
        mData.getItems().removeAll(mData.getItems());
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        isFlipped = true;
        loadData(false, -1);
        closeMenu();
    } else {

        mData.getItems().removeAll(mData.getItems());
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        isFlipped = false;
        loadData(false, 1);
        closeMenu();
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Again, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a public method **in your RecyclerView** code, e.g:

```
public void clearAll(){
    mData.clear();
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And then call that function from your activity (or Fragment):

private void flip() {

```
if (!isFlipped) {
    mAdapter.clearAll();
    isFlipped = true;
    loadData(false, -1);
    closeMenu();
} else {
    mAdapter.clearAll();
    isFlipped = false;
    loadData(false, 1);
    closeMenu();
}
```

}